# Reference error: Com is not defined"

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I'm new to Blackberry. I use phonegap to create cross platform applications. My html file is very simple. It looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="www/phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added phonegap-1.3.0.js file that is available for blackberry phonegap.
My config.xml contains these permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"     xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" version="1.0.0.0">
<name>Cps1</name>
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.app.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.system" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="com.phonegap" required="false" version="1.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.system.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.BrowserArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" /> 
<feature id="blackberry.identity" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.utils" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<content src="index.html"/>
</widget>
```

On debugging it shows "Reference error: Com is not defined" in phonegap.js file. Can anyone please help me as what else has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version number of phonegap u added and try with

and check the phone gap jar file is added to u r project or not??